# What is the "iterated definability" limit of first-order logic?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

Roughly speaking, given a set-sized logic $\mathcal{L}$ let $\mathcal{L}'$ be gotten by adding to $\mathcal{L}$ the ability to quantify over $\mathcal{L}$-definable relations. (The details are a bit tedious, so I've put the rigorous definition at the end of this question.) Note that $\mathcal{L}'$ is always strictly stronger than $\mathcal{L}$: let $\kappa$ be some cardinal greater than the set of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas in the language $\{<\}$, and consider the least $\mathcal{L}$-undefinable element of the structure $(\kappa;<)$. We can iterate this jump operation up to any ordinal $\alpha$ by taking unions at limit stages as usual (since we're not worrying about syntax there is no "notation"-flavored issue) to get $\mathcal{L}^{(\alpha)}$. Even iterating through all the ordinals makes sense; call the result $\mathcal{L}^{(\infty)}$.

I'm interested in pinning down $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\infty)}$. Here's what I know so far:

- $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\infty)}$ is (always up to expressive strength) a sublogic of $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}^L=\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}\cap L$. More generally, if $M$ is an inner model and $\mathcal{L}$ is a set-sized sublogic of $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}^M$ which is appropriately definable in $M$, then $\mathcal{L}'\subseteq\mathcal{L}^M_{\infty,\omega}$ as well.
- $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\infty)}$ is strictly weaker than $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}^L$: if $(r_i)_{i\in\omega}$ are sufficiently mutually Cohen generic (say, generic over a countable elementary submodel of $L_{\omega_1}$), then the $\{<,\in\}$-structures $\omega\sqcup\{r_{2i}:i\in\omega\}$ and $\omega\sqcup\{r_{2i+1}: i\in\omega\}$ are $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\infty)}$-equivalent but not $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}^L$-equivalent.
- The argument of the previous bulletpoint implies that the $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\infty)}$-definable relations on $(\omega;<)$ fall well short of the constructible ones. On the other hand, it's also easy to see that they reach well past the hyperarithmetic: the $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\omega_1^{CK})}$-definable relations are exactly the hyperarithmetic ones, and $\mathcal{O}$ is then $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\omega_1^{CK}+1)}$-definable since a computable linear order is a well-order iff it supports a hyperarithmetic jump sequence.
- Finally, despite its clear weaknesses, for every countable structure $\mathfrak{A}$ the automorphism orbit relation on elements (or $n$-tuples for fixed $n$) of $\mathfrak{A}$ is $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\infty)}$-definable (this is just Scott's argument).

My main question is whether there is a better description of this logic as a whole:

> **Question 1**: Is there a snappier description of $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\infty)}$?

The definition of $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\infty)}$ is "bottom-up" (a more snappy version: it's the smallest possibly-class-sized logic containing $\mathsf{FOL}$ and containing $\mathcal{L}'$ whenever $\mathcal{L}$ is a set-sized logic it contains). I would be especially be interested in a "top-down" definition, such as "the largest logic containing $\mathsf{FOL}$ with *[tameness properties]*." Lindstrom's theorem is one motivating example of such a definition, but there are others - e.g. [Barwise's analysis of $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484372900022).

My secondary question, for which I at least have a conjecture, is about its arithmetic power specifically:

> **Question 2**: What are the $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\infty)}$-definable relations on the naturals?

My guess is that these are exactly the relations in $L_{\beta_0}$, where ${\beta_0}$ is the smallest "gap ordinal" (= such that $L_{\beta_0}\cap\mathbb{R}=L_{\beta_0+1}\cap\mathbb{R}$). This ${\beta_0}$ is known to also be the least ordinal such that $L_{\beta_0}\models\mathsf{ZFC^-}$, or such that $L_{\beta_0}\cap\mathbb{R}\models\mathsf{Z}_2$. See [Putnam](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-4/issue-4/A-note-on-constructible-sets-of-integers/10.1305/ndjfl/1093957652.full), [Marek/Srebrny](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484374900059/), or [Madore (entry 2.17)](http://www.madore.org/%7Edavid/math/ordinal-zoo.pdf).

---

### Details

Here's a more precise definition of $\mathcal{L}'$. We take the closure of the $\mathcal{L}$-formulas under the addition of a whole family of new relation quantifiers $$\bigtriangledown^{\mathcal{L},p}_{\delta,\eta,\rho_1,...,\rho_n}.$$ Here the $\mathcal{L}$-superscript indicates the logic with respect to which we are quantifying over definable relations, $p\in\omega$ indicates the arity of the relations being quantified over, and $\delta,\eta,\rho_1,...,\rho_n$ are $\mathcal{L}$-formulas with respective arities $d, e, r_1,...,r_n$ such that $e=2d$ and each $r_i$ is divisible by $d$. The semantics of these new quantifiers is given as follows:

- In any structure $\mathfrak{A}$, if $\eta^\mathfrak{A}$ is an equivalence relation on $\delta^\mathfrak{A}$ and each $\rho_i^\mathfrak{A}$ is well-defined on $\delta^\mathfrak{A}/\eta^\mathfrak{A}$ in the obvious sense, then "$\bigtriangledown^{\mathcal{L},p}_{\delta,\eta,\rho_1,...,\rho_n}X[\mathit{stuff}]$" (with $X$ a $p$-ary relation variable) means

> "For every $\eta^\mathfrak{A}$-invariant relation $X\subseteq(\delta^\mathfrak{A})^p$ such that $X/\eta^\mathfrak{A}$ is $\mathcal{L}$-definable in the related structure $(\delta^\mathfrak{A}/\eta^\mathfrak{A}; \rho_1,...,\rho_n)$, it is the case that $[\mathit{stuff}]$."

- On the other hand, if $\delta,\eta,\rho_1,...,\rho_n$ do not satisfy the above conditions in $\mathfrak{A}$, then we interpret $\bigtriangledown^{\mathcal{L},p}_{\delta,\eta,\rho_1,...,\rho_n}$ in some fixed trivial way (say, always outputting $\perp$).

Note that when we iterate $'$ we get multiple $\bigtriangledown$-quantifiers; so, for example, $\mathsf{FOL}^{(\omega)}$ has a separate quantifier (family) $\bigtriangledown^{\mathsf{FOL}^{(n)}}$ for each $n\in\omega$. *(Incidentally, a stronger version of this construction was suggested in [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605261/non-henkin-non-full-semantics-for-second-order-logic/4605604#4605604), but I've ultimately decided that the more limited approach here is more natural.)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question properly (I'm not sure whether I do), then it looks like your conjecture for question 2 is correct, i.e. $L_{\beta_0}\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$. Here is a hastily written sketch.

For in fact, letting $N_\alpha$ be the set of $\mathcal{L}^{(\alpha)}$ relations on $\omega$, then $N_\alpha=L_{\omega+\alpha}\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ for all $\alpha\leq\beta_0$, and $\beta_0$ is a closure point.

The small issue here is to see that over $N_\alpha$, we can simulate $L_\alpha$ definably from parameters, assuming that $N_\alpha=L_\alpha\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$.

Suppose $\alpha=\beta+1$. Since $L_\beta$ projects to $\omega$, there is a real $x\in N_\alpha$ which codes $L_\beta$.
We can refer to $x$, since this is given by some $\mathcal{L}^{(\alpha)}$ relation. Then in fact for all ordinals in $\gamma\in[\alpha,\kappa_\alpha)$,
where $\kappa_\alpha$ is the least admissible $\kappa>\alpha$,
we can define simulate $L_\gamma$ over $N_\gamma$ by looking at all models $M$
coded by reals which satisfy ``$V=L[x]$''; all of these are wellfounded,
because otherwise the wellfounded part is a model of KP, but it easily enough follows then that $N\notin L_{\kappa_\alpha}$, so $N\notin N_\gamma$. So over $N_\gamma$ we can simulate $L_\gamma$, and hence define (from parameters) all reals in $L_{\gamma+1}$.

So we get that $N_{\kappa_\alpha}=L_{\kappa_\alpha}\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$.

Now suppose that $\alpha$ is a limit of admissibles, and we have $N_\alpha=L_\alpha\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$. Then over $N_\alpha$, we can simulate $L_\alpha$ by looking at all models $M$
coded by reals, which satisfy ``$V=L$'',
and are wellfounded in $N_\alpha$,
i.e. have no descending sequence through their ordinals which is in $N_\alpha$.
(Any illfounded such model $M$ gets into some $L_\kappa$ for some admissible $\kappa<\alpha$, but then we get a descending sequence before $\alpha$.)
So we can simulate $L_\alpha$ over $N_\alpha$ as desired.

Comment: I think this is right, but let me read through it more carefully later today.

Comment: I think the only thing that needs to be added is that when we look at models coded by reals it's enough to look at reals already in the relevant layer of $N$, but this is immediate. Thanks! (I'm going to hold off on awarding the bounty for now since the other component of the question is still open.) Meanwhile re: your first sentence, is there something in particular that I could clarify in the question? I'm generally interested in this sort of topic and I'd like to make my post maximally understandable.

Comment: As an upper bound, I think this works for all structures: if we define an analogue $L_{\mathfrak{A},-}$ of the $L$-hierarchy starting with a copy of a structure $\mathfrak{A}$ as urelements, the $\mathsf{FOL^{(\infty)}}$-definable relations on $\mathfrak{A}$ should all be in $L_{\mathfrak{A},\theta}$ for $\theta$ least such that $L_{\mathfrak{A},\theta}\cap\mathcal{P}^{<\omega}(\mathfrak{A})=L_{\mathfrak{A},\theta+1}\cap\mathcal{P}^{<\omega}(\mathfrak{A})$. It's not clear to me, though, that this is always sharp.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{P}^{<\omega}$?

Comment: The set of all finite-arity relations. (It was a typo, but it's too late to edit now.)